# create a filtered list of dictionaries based on existing list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries read in from csv DictReader that represent rows of a csv file:

```
    rows = [{"id":"123","date":"1/1/18","foo":"bar"},
            {"id":"123","date":"2/2/18", "foo":"baz"}]
```

I would like to create a new dictionary, where only unique ID's are stored. But I would like to only keep the row entry with the most recent date. Based on the above example, it would keep the row with date 2/2/18.

I was thinking of doing something like this, but having trouble translating the pseudocode in the else statement into actual python.

I can figure out the part of checking the two dates for which is more recent, but having the most trouble figuring out how I check the new list for the dictionary that contains the same id and then retrieving the date from that row.

Note: Unfortunately, due to resource constraints on our platform I am **unable to use pandas for this project.**

```
new_data = []
for row in rows:
    if row['id'] not in new_data:
        new_data.append(row)
    else:
        check the element in new_data with the same id as row['id']
        if that element's date value is less recent: 
            replace it with the current row
        else :
            continue to next row in rows
```

Comment: I would suggest making a function to compare dates, then compare you date strings from right to left taking the greater one and moving down if they are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a function to convert your date (as string) to a date (as date).

```
import datetime

def to_date(date_str):
  d1, m1, y1 = [int(s) for s in date_str.split('/')]
  return datetime.date(y1, m1, d1)
```

I assumed your date format is d/m/yy. Consider using `datetime.strptime` to parse your dates, as illustrated by Alex Hall's answer.

Then, the idea is to loop over your rows and store them in a new structure (here, a dict whose keys are the IDs). If a key already exists, compare its date with the current row, and take the right one. Following your pseudo-code, this leads to:

```
rows = [{"id":"123","date":"1/1/18","foo":"bar"},
        {"id":"123","date":"2/2/18", "foo":"baz"}]

new_data = dict()
for row in rows:
    existing = new_data.get(row['id'], None)
      if existing is None or to_date(existing['date']) < to_date(row['date']):
          new_data[row['id']] = row
```

If your want your `new_data` variable to be a list, use `new_data = list(new_data.values())`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

rows = [{"id":"123","date":"1/1/18","foo":"bar"},
            {"id":"123","date":"2/2/18", "foo":"baz"}]

def parse_date(d):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%y").date()

tmp_dict = {}
for row in rows:
    if row['id'] not in tmp_dict.keys():
        tmp_dict['id'] = row
    else:
        if parse_date(row['date']) > parse_date(tmp_dict[row['id']]):
            tmp_dict['id'] = row


print tmp_dict.values()
```

output

```
[{'date': '2/2/18', 'foo': 'baz', 'id': '123'}]
```

Note: you can merge the two `if` to `if row['id'] not in tmp_dict.keys() || parse_date(row['date']) > parse_date(tmp_dict[row['id']])` for cleaner and shorter code

Comment: Just do `if row['id'] not in tmp_dict`. They `.keys()` is not needed and in Python 2 it will slow things down greatly.

Comment: You can avoid the second lookup of `row['id']`, see my answer. This could increase performances if you have a lot of data to process.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, work with proper date objects, not strings. Here is how to parse them:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

rows = [{"id": "123", "date": "1/1/18", "foo": "bar"},
        {"id": "123", "date": "2/2/18", "foo": "baz"}]

for row in rows:
    row['date'] = datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%d/%m/%y').date()
```

(check if the format is correct)

Then for the actual task:

```
new_data = {}
for row in rows:
    new_data[row['id']] = max(new_data.get(row['id'], date.min),
                              row['date'])

print(new_data.values())
```

---

Alternatively:

Here are some generic utility functions that work well here which I use in many places:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def group_by_key_func(iterable, key_func):
    """
    Create a dictionary from an iterable such that the keys are the result of evaluating a key function on elements
    of the iterable and the values are lists of elements all of which correspond to the key.
    """
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for item in iterable:
        result[key_func(item)].append(item)
    return result

def group_by_key(iterable, key):
    return group_by_key_func(iterable, lambda x: x[key])
```

Then the solution can be written as:

```
by_id = group_by_key(rows, 'id')

for id_num, group in list(by_id.items()):
    by_id[id_num] = max(group, key=lambda r: r['date'])

print(by_id.values())
```

This is less efficient than the first solution because it creates lists along the way that are discarded, but I use the general principles in many places and I thought of it first, so here it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to utilize classes as much as I do, then you could make your own class to do this:

```
from datetime import date
rows = [
    {"id":"123","date":"1/1/18","foo":"bar"},
    {"id":"123","date":"2/2/18", "foo":"baz"},
    {"id":"456","date":"3/3/18","foo":"bar"},
    {"id":"456","date":"1/1/18","foo":"bar"}
]

class unique(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        #Add key if missing or replace key if date is newer
        if key not in self or self[key]["date"] < value["date"]:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

data = unique()                   #Initialize new class based on dict
for row in rows:
    d, m, y = map(int, row["date"].split('/')) #Split date into parts
    row["date"] = date(y, m, d)   #Replace date value
    data[row["id"]] = row         #Set new data. Will overwrite same ids with more recent

print data.values()
```

Outputs:

```
[
    {'date': datetime.date(18, 2, 2), 'foo': 'baz', 'id': '123'},
    {'date': datetime.date(18, 3, 3), 'foo': 'bar', 'id': '456'}
]
```

Keep in mind that `data` is a dict that essentially overrides the [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) method that uses IDs as keys. And the dates are [`date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects) objects so they can be compared easily.

Comment: You can parse the dates however you want to (from the other answers), as long as it's consistent. But it's necessary to compare the dates properly against each other.